How to use reveal.js with Deno Fresh?
In my understanding, reveal.js is just vanilla JS, so there should be no problem when using it with Deno.
On routes/index.tsx I have:
import Island from "../islands/Island.tsx";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Island />
  );
}

And on islands/Island.tsx I have:
import {useEffect} from 'preact/hooks'
import Reveal from '../reveal/js/index.js';

export default function Island() {
  useEffect(()=> {
    const deck = new Reveal()
    deck.initialize();
  }, [] ) 
  return (
    <div class="reveal">
      <div class="slides">
        <section>Slide 1</section>
        <section>Slide 2</section>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) 
}

I expect this to return a basic slide on the browser, but it shows the text Resume presentation at the bottom left corner. Why is that?

useEffect only runs in the browser, so the if (IS_BROWSER) bit should be redundant. Use useEffect(() => { ... }, []) to make sure you're only running the effect once though. Without the empty array, the effect will rerun on every single render, which you probably don't want.

In this code I'm not sure how it will be re-render without my acknowledgement, so I guess it should be fine. Even with the empty array the issue isn't solved

Don't forget to add the styles to routes/_app.tsx:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/reveal.js@4.3.1/dist/reveal.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/reveal.js@4.3.1/dist/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/reveal.js@4.3.1/dist/theme/simple.css" />

